# No se puede convertir implicitamente el tipo "double" en "double[] usando Math.Pow

Tags: c#, double

Ayuda 
estaba usando esta fórmula:

```
A * (Math.Pow(Xo, Potencia)) + B * (Math.Pow(Xo, Potencia2)) - C
```

donde `Xo` es ingresada por teclado y convertida con:

`Xo = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());`

Y en la fórmula me aparece el error:

> No se puede convertir implicitamente el tipo "double" en "double[]"

Antes ya había usado esa fórmula y no me aparecia ningún error, creo que el problema puede ser esa conversion a double. Como puedo solucionarlo

Comment: Mira [ask] <- ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] <- ACA para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Xo de que tipo es?

Comment: Dudo que el problema sea la conversión, te recomiendo que agregues el código completo, de como calculas `A`,`B` y `C`, sino es sumamente complicado ayudart

Comment: La respuesta es obvia: estas intentando asignar un `double` aun objeto de tipo `double[]`. Pero si quieres ayuda tendras que mostrar todo el codigo relevante ya que es dificil decir cual es la variable de tipo `double[]`

Comment: declaraste alguna variable como double[],
adicionalmente yo prefiero usar double.parse en lugar de convert

Comment: Se necesita más código para averiguar lo que sucede, con esas dos líneas no es suficiente información.